# Making lookup table for performing Lookup(inRaster, lookupField)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy

I want to replace the Digital number (DN) values in a raster file with some other values which are present in a text file;in the text file, I have a table which it's first column are all possible DN and on the next column I have corresponding values to be replaced.

First of all, I want to know which ways make it possible to use this table to replace DN values with Python specially arcpy?

I want to use Lookup(inRaster, lookupField) in ArcMap but I do not know how can I introduce my separate text file to this statement as a lookup table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [Lookup](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//009z000000sn000000) tool help page, the look up table should be derived from the raster attribute table.

Raster datasets that contain attribute tables typically have cell values that represent or define a class, group, category, or membership. For example, a satellite image may have undergone a classification analysis to create a raster dataset that defines land uses.

To build a raster table use  "Build Raster Attribute Table" tool. (Note that your raster should be single band!)

Then add your csv table to the map and do a join to append the attributes of your lookup table to the raster.

Finally use Lookup tool to change and update the DN values.

Comment: Happy to hear that. If this is your answer, consider marking it as answer.